# Bootstrap Popover inside dynamic Select Option

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a popover which creates content dynamic and wants to interactuate with the option is selected.

I have a `select` and one of my `option` has to pop up a `popover` which have a form with 'Accept' and 'Cancel' `buttons`. But first of all, doesn't show on my page, and the second one (trying in the w3schools editors where at last I can show the popover) the Cancel button doesn't hide the current popover.

This is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3yq1o43/2/) for the popover working but  not closing (only now it has a console.log which try to show 'hello' but doesn't work)

And this is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9d7j4we/) for the trying to get the popover when 'No Disponible' is selected.

Anyone can explain why doesn't work any of my attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with solution for the first half https://jsfiddle.net/c3yq1o43/3/ . That is **closing** of the **popover** on **clicking** **Cancel** button

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  closepop = function(){
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
   }
        
    var pop = $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html:true,
    content: function(){
     return "<form name='statusForm'>"+
           "<div class='form-group'>"+
                     "<textarea class='form-control' name='estado' placeholder='Motivo de la no-disponibilidad' required></textarea>"+
                    "</div>"+
           "<button class='button btn btn-success' type='button'>Aceptar</button>"+
                    "<button class='button btn btn-success' type='button' onclick='closepop()'>Cancelar</button>"+
                "</form>"
    }});  
    
    
    
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Popover Example</h3>
    <p>Popovers are not CSS-only plugins, and must therefore be initialized with jQuery: select the specified element and call the popover() method.</p>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header">Toggle popover</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

I trying to make the second half of the question.
Little bit of confusion..

On selection of 'No Disponible' option you want to show the **popover**???

Comment: Thank you for the first half!! Yes, is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xrkxdedg/3/ when I click "No disponible" It has to show the form, and if Cancel is pressed, close it

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. I want to click on "No disponible" and **without** closing the `select` show the popover